# iOS 8 – Glitch when presenting view controller quickly after setting key window or dismissing and instanly presenting another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Since testing my app on iOS 8, I find a work around view controllers initialization and presentation really baaadly slow.

I used to work with a code similar to this on iOS 6 & 7:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ....

    [self.window setRootViewController:_rootController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Conditions

    if (#first launch condition#) {
        // quite small controller containing Welcome showcase
        WelcomeViewController *w = ....
        [_rootViewController presentViewController:w animated:NO];
    }

    else if (#last opened item condition#) {
        // pretty big container, root view controller contains
        // a grid view which opens Item detail container the same way
        ItemDetailController *item = ....
        [_rootViewController presentViewController:item animated:NO];
    }

}
```

This became a really sluggish hell with iOS 8. Root view controller now appears visible for 0.5-1 second and then instantly redraws the screen with presented one. Moreover, the slowness of the presentation began to cause an `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions _rootViewController` warning.

Initial quick hint was to move both conditions with calls to another function and call it with a zero-delay so it's processed in next main run loop:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(postAppFinishedPresentation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

or something like that. This fixes the unballanced calls issue, but the visual gap (rootviewcontroller, gap, presented one) becomes (obviously) even bigger.

The slowness of the presentation is also obvious when you call something usual as:

```
// Example: Delegate caught finished Sign In dialog,
//          dismiss it and instantly switch to Profile controller

-(void)signInViewControllerDidFinishedSuccessfully
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
         UserProfileViewController *userProfile = ...
         [self presentViewController:userProfile animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

which should be completely fair piece of code, which used to perform direct transition without a visible flick of parent view controller on iOS 7. Now, same thing – parent flicks during the transition, even it's both handled without animation.

Does anybody face this as an issue? Any solutions? I'd love to solve this without a need to do some hilarious magic with `UIWindow`s for each thing I need to transit flawlessly.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Also dealing with the same type issue. No solution yet. In my code, iOS 7 works beautifully but iOS 8 has an awful delay between a dismiss/present viewController combo. Tried putting both calls in the same animation block to no avail. Tried both in the same call with no animation, still nothing. iOS 8 has so many hidden gifts...

Comment: Did you guys find any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Is this a bug in iOS8 ?

Comment: Have you tried moving the condition part to your RootViewController's `viewDidAppear` (and add some logic to prevent they from presenting multiple times)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the requirement is restricted to have root view controller and present anything over there.

But according to your code it's have welcome view controller thing and I think in this case, this logic is more useful.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Conditions

    if (#first launch condition#) {
        // quite small controller containing Welcome showcase
        WelcomeViewController *w = ....

        //It can be navigation or tab bar controller which have "w" as rootviewcontroller
        [self.window setRootViewController:w];
    }

    else if (#last opened item condition#) {
        // pretty big container, root view controller contains
        // a grid view which opens Item detail container the same way
        ItemDetailController *item = ....
        //It can be navigation or tab bar controller which have "item" as rootviewcontroller
        [self.window setRootViewController:item];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: Well, there is no requirement or limitation on `UIWindow` use, so this may partially be the way, but that requires the app to be implemented completely diffently – let's suppose with some Window manager and this stuff. But this is generally a bit advanced flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Storyboard, why not try:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController *_rootController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root"];
[self.window setRootViewController:_rootController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if (vcToShow == 1) {
     ViewController2 *w = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];
    [_rootController presentViewController:w animated:NO completion:nil];
}
else if (vcToShow == 2) {
    ViewController2 *w = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc3"];
    [_rootController presentViewController:w animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

It looks like there is no delay here.

Answer (score 0):

The delay I had from a dismiss/present pair was fixed by this. It may or may not help your instance. I had to completely change my strategy of displaying/dismissing modal view controllers under iOS 8:

```
[_rootViewController presentViewController:vc1 animated:NO completion:nil];

if(iNeedToDisplayVC2) {
     [vc1 presentViewController:vc2 animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

So once I am done with vc2 later on, I dismiss both vc1 and vc2 in the same call. This strategy works under iOS 7 as well. I assume earlier versions too but I did not test them.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS8, I've found the old presentation is not quite completed yet in the completion block, and calling dismiss or present right away can lead to console messages and sometimes the present/dismiss does not even occur.  I have had some success by adding a further delayed perform to the second presentation:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
         UserProfileViewController *userProfile = ...
         [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
             [self presentViewController:userProfile animated:NO];
         }];
    }];
```